# Date picker is not resetting?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have two date fields, from and to date.If i change the from date to date will get changed , using on change function in date picker. i have reset button in my form, if i reset the values should get reset. but my problem is if i select the from date (i.e 5/02/17) and the to date will be (i.e 5/02/17) i will not allow the user to select the future date

```
$('#fromDate').datepicker({
    format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
     endDate: '+0d',
    autoclose: true
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('#toDate').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
    var endDateValue = $("#toDate").val();
    var date = new Date(minDate);
    var dd = date.getDate();
    var mm = date.getMonth() + 1; 

    var yyyy = date.getFullYear()+543;
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }
    var startDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
    console.log(yyyy+ "endDateValue "+endDateValue);
    if(endDateValue === ""){
        $("#toDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date(startDate)));
    }else if(endDateValue < startDate){
        $("#toDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date(startDate)));
    }

});
$('#toDate').datepicker({
    format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
     endDate: '+0d',
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight:false
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    var endDateValue = $("#fromDate").val();
    if(endDateValue === ""){

        var date = new Date(minDate);
        var dd = date.getDate();
        var mm = date.getMonth() + 1; 

        var yyyy = date.getFullYear()+543;
        if (dd < 10) {
            dd = '0' + dd;
        }
        if (mm < 10) {
            mm = '0' + mm;
        }
        var endDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
        console.log(yyyy+ "endDate "+endDate);
        $("#fromDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date(endDate)));
    }

});
```

i have used above code to change my to date as well as from date. if i click clear button

```
$("#clearButton").click(function(){

    $('#toDate').datepicker('update','');

});
```

i wrote the above code. my problem is if i click clear button , i could not able to clear my To date. (i.e I have selected the from date and clicked on clear button the to date is still my from date. i could not go beyond that ). I have tried all the ways but could not able to resolve. help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setDate :

```
$('#toDate').datepicker('setDate', null);
```

OR

Redraw the date picker

```
$('#toDate').datepicker( "refresh" );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
$('#toDate').val('')
```

or

```
$('#toDate').datepicker("clearDates");
```

or

```
$('#toDate').val('').datepicker('update');
```

or

```
$('#toDate').datepicker({
    clearBtn: true
});
```